# Disable Pagespeed image optimisation for specific CSS defined background images

Tags: html, css, pagespeed, mod-pagespeed

With Pagespeed enabled, is there a way to disable image optimisation for specific CSS defined background images?

For example, there's a **pagespeed_no_transform** tag we can add to images to disable optimisation :

```
<img src="..." pagespeed_no_transform />
```

I'm seeking an equivalent for CSS defined background images if possible. I.e I'd like to turn off Pagespeed image optimisation for situation :

```
.teaser1 {
    background: url('image.png') no-repeat;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For reference, answered my own question by turning off Pagespeed for a specific image path within my app conf file :

```
ModPagespeedDisallow "*/path/to/images/not/to/be/optimised/*"
```